# React Native add to state array if value does not exist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to know the best way to add a value to an array of the value does not exist in my state variable. The current code works but I a newbie and not sure if I am doing this correctly. This function is fired when a button is pressed

```
const App = () => {
  
  const [answered, setAnswered] = useState([])

  const handleConnectionAnswer = deviceId => {
    if (!anwsered.includes(deviceId)) {
      setAnswered(prev => [...prev, deviceId]);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: That seems to be correct

Comment: It's correct actually, but instead of array it would be better to use map/object/set in this use-case as it would be more efficient to read and manipulate in O(1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're doing it right or you can simply do it like

```
if (!anwsered.includes(deviceId)) {
  setAnswered([...answered, deviceId]);
}
```